# libharu library loads the whole pdf into memory

Tags: c++, pdf, pdf-generation, libharu

Is there a way to use the libharu API such that the pdf is not held entirely into memory?

The use case:
I'm trying to put together several images and the memory used by the application is increasing along with the number of images added in the pdf file.

Comment: Why not ask this question [on github?](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/issues).

Comment: I was reluctant to post an issue as they don't have a discussion page. I added the question now: https://github.com/libharu/libharu/issues/300